# Developing Geo-location apps for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, geolocation

How does one build a directory of 'Spots' for users to check-in to in a native iPhone app? Or, does the developer borrow data from, let's say, Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

When you Use data obtained from another network or source, you take a risk that the data may change and or may not be accurate, The data may cease to exist, (more so with google, LOL, one minute they are there like gangbusters, the next they are like "Gone" no explanation no apologies, just missing in action, if your developing an application for a business its always best to use your own data sources.

That may be more expensive but its the only way you will have any kind of control over your application resources,.

Comment: And just what does "your own data sources" mean in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can go both ways, it depends on what you want to do and how you designed it to do it. You can have a prerecorded and static database of spots, or you can update it sometimes connecting to some server or you can do it all dynamically by loading each time data from the internet.

Which one to choose? first you shall design your app having in mind something like:

- How many times will these datas change
- How frequently will these changes happen
- How much will it cost to do an update

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Developing your own database of places is likely to be quite an undertaking (and your competitors have a big head start). Google is [beginning to provide their Places API](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/07/checking-in-with-places-api.html) for "check-in" style applications, so you may be able to get in on their beta.